# First time on ubuntu, fan is going crazy 24/24!

Tags: fan

I'm gonna keep it real and short, got an asus rog gl552vw, installed ubuntu 16.04 on SSD  and when I boot it to the desktop the fan started to run loudly 24/24.  I tried  so many things, still couldn't do it. Any good source or doc is highly apreciated. I made a CPU scan and saw 1,3% to /ascid, also tried fancontrol but got some issues..

Comment: what is the GPU for this pc?

Comment: Is there any command to find out?